# Tokenize string - wrong result

Tags: bash, busybox, ifs, positional-parameter

Wrong tokenize of string

For extraction of app version from command output

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.3.46

string='Version: 19.08.19-14:25'
IFS=" -:" set -- $string
echo $2
```

I expect that `$2` will have value `19.08.19`. But result is `19.08.19 14 25`.

Answer (score 1):

The word splitting happens before the value of IFS has changed (see SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION in `man bash`). You need to set IFS in a separate statement.

```
IFS=" -:"
set -- $string
```

Don't forget to set it back if the script does anything else.

Comment: Alternatively `IFS=" -:"; set -- $string`